# WordPress Database: Include a custom field in mysql query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

```
SELECT DISTINCT    
            city_latitude.post_id,
            city_latitude.meta_value as charity_latitude,
            city_longitude.meta_value as charity_longitude,
            ((ACOS(SIN(%f * PI() / 180) * SIN(city_latitude.meta_value * PI() / 180) + COS(%f * PI() / 180) * COS(city_latitude.meta_value * PI() / 180) * COS((%f - city_longitude.meta_value) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance,
            FxFfekP0_posts.post_title
            FROM 
            FxFfekP0_postmeta AS city_latitude
            LEFT JOIN FxFfekP0_postmeta as city_longitude ON city_latitude.post_id = city_longitude.post_id
            INNER JOIN FxFfekP0_posts ON FxFfekP0_posts.ID = city_latitude.post_id
            WHERE city_latitude.meta_key = 'latitude' AND city_longitude.meta_key = 'longitude'
            HAVING distance < %d
            ORDER BY distance ASC
```

How do I add to this query and include a custom field of `charity_name` as a column? I'm having a hard time with this one...

**NOTE:** I did post this at `wordpress.stackoverflow.com` but I was advised to post it over here because it's far more of a MySQL question.

Comment: Change 'WHERE' to 'AND'. Change the subsequent 'AND' to 'WHERE'

Comment: What? @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should be just about right- search this site for any bits that don't immediately make sense...

```
SELECT lat.post_id
     , lat.meta_value charity_latitude
     , lon.meta_value charity_longitude
     , name.meta_value charity_name
     , geo_distance_km(user_lat,user_lon,lat.meta_value,lon.meta_value) distance
     , p.post_title
  FROM FxFfekP0_postmeta lat
  LEFT 
  JOIN FxFfekP0_postmeta lon 
    ON lon.post_id = lat .post_id
   AND lon.meta_key = 'longitude'
  LEFT
  JOIN FxFfekP0_posts p
    ON p.ID = lat.post_id
  LEFT
  JOIN FxFfekP0_postmeta name
    ON name.post_id = lat.post_id
   AND name.meta_key = 'charity_name'
 WHERE lat.meta_key = 'latitude' 
AND geo_distance_km(user_lat,user_lon,lat.meta_value,lon.meta_value) < %d
        ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Comment: `geo_distance_km` ?

Comment: @dcolumbus indeed. See you in October.

Comment: ... my apologies for not responding to your answer sooner. I had to move onto other issues and I did not receive the notification. I know that the `geo_distance_km` is a function, but where should that function be defined, if this query is being run singularly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It should be defined in the database !?!?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to learn more about database manipulation. I have never defined a function within the database itself. I'm using Sequel Pro to manage my databases, if that helps. I'll also Google how to do such a thing if it's a huge waste of your time to explain. I'm assuming it's a `Trigger`, but maybe not.

Comment: I don't know anything about Sequel Pro. In MySQL, there's not much mystery to constructing this kind of function. A copy-paste will probably do the trick.

Comment: Indeed. Well, at least I figured out how to actually add the function to the database. Now I see that the query isn't actually accomplishing what I'm looking for... it's returning nothing, and there should be dozens of results.

Comment: In which case consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements together with a desired result

Comment: Your `get_distance_km` functions is working fine. It's the query above that isn't returning results.